# Downloading Excel from Google API random error - Response status code does not indicate success

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Trying to download Excel (*.xlsx) files from Google Drive.

When calling DriveService.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync() I get this error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException 
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error

- This error happens randomly
- The Excel files range in size from 0.5 MB to 15 MB
- One file does seem to error more frequently.  It is 4 MB
- This happened randomly every month or so.  Starting this week it happens nearly every time I run code that downloads 18 Excel files.

I created a catch/retry mechanism which seems to work with 3 attempts.  I still would like a fix

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(map.Credentials);
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
DriveService driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

string path = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + map.Path + "?alt=media";
var x = driveService.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(path);
byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;  // Randomly throws exception
```